# How to communicate with existing java process

Tags: java, shell

How can I pass some values from a shell script to a Java program that is already running?

Comment: @ ssbecse You seems to have angered a lot of commenters below revising the question in a way that rendered their perfectly valid answers as invalid. %-| Please be more clear next time. We do not read minds here, not for free.

Comment: The original question was changed. My answer was valid when the original question was posted.

Answer (score 5):

Standalone Java application is already running, so command line parameters are out of question.

Simplest alternatives remaining are polling for files, sockets and HTTP server.

**Polling for files:**

Make you java app to read a specific directory once in a few seconds. If a file appears in that directory, read it and do as it says. Make your shell script to form that file.

**Socket:**

Make you java app to listen on a socket. Use netcat or a similar utility to send commands to that socket.

**HTTP Server:**

Start an HTTP listener within the Java process. Use wget or similar utility to post your commands to that listener:

```
HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 5);
httpServer.createContext("/", new TileServerRequestHandler());
httpServer.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
httpServer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the params to a file that your process interrogates periodically? Crude, but it'd work ( but with a lot of usage limitations ).
Or have your process listen on a socket and get your shell script to send the parameters down the socket.

Answer (score 0):

See how to pass command line parameters to java [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

EDIT: new information in the question means this is no longer a suitable solution

Comment: Down voter please note the answer was perfectly valid for the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

One option for communicating with a Java process is the [Java Messaging Service API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service). Your shell script could launch a JMS client to send messages to the main application.

Comment: hello, I am really stuck in a similar problem, can u explain more regarding similar design pattern

Comment: @NirajSanghani I can. I can also share my hourly consulting rate with you, if you're interested. But given that you're on a Q&A site already, I would suggest doing enough research on your own to be able to ask more specific questions, and then post them here!